# My acronym suddenly breaks

Tags: acronyms

I have a list of acronyms that it is working well, but suddenly after the chapter 3 acronym `\ac{acl}[ACL]{Access Control List}` it breaks. All acronyms after it appears as `@<>@<>@acl (ACL)`.
I am using sharelatex.com. The main log output doesn't show any error about acronyms. I am not using acronyms on footnotes. 
Which log can I see more details? How can I fix this?

Thanks

**Edit**
I included `\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}` and all the acronyms worked.
But now my acronym list disappeared. I am using this to set the list of acronyms:

```
\input{acronyms}
\listofacronyms
\printglossaries
```

And the list of acronyms I am building like this:

```
\begin{acronym}[ACRONYM]
\newacronym{acl}{ACL}{Access Control List}
\newacronym{afm}{AFM}{Alphabet Frequency Matrix}
\end{acronym}
```

And I am using `\gls{acl}` to show the acronym.

Comment: If that acronym worked before chapter 3, there probably is an error unrelated to the actual acronym introduced in chapter 3, like missing brackets or such. I don't use sharelatex, so I can't help you with the location of the log files. Could you post a MWE so we can see what is going on?

Comment: And if you wonder what a MWE is, [look here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/1424).

Comment: You seem to be mixing the `acronym` and `glossaries` packages code. `\begin{acronym}` is provided by `acronym.sty` but not by `glossaries.sty`.

Comment: @felipe  You'll need to build the glossary first -- either using `\makenoidxglossaries` or `\makeglossaries` (depends on how the index is constructed -- see the manual of `glossaries`!) in the preamble.

Comment: thanks, I got using `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but `\newacronym{acl}{ACL}{Access Control List}` breaks the function. If you rename it to something else like `\newacronym{accesscl}{ACL}{Access Control List}`, it should work. I think it's because `acl` does not work, because there is also the command `\acl` and the package has some trouble with it.